# GTK move focus to main window when clicking outside widget

Tags: c++, focus, gtk3

Is it possible to move keyboard focus to main window when the user clicks outside any widget, or on a widget that do not want keyboard focus. I tried

```
gboolean Window::Impl::mouse_down(GtkWidget* widget,GdkEventButton* event,void* user_data)
{
auto self=reinterpret_cast<Impl*>(user_data);
auto w=gtk_window_get_focus(GTK_WINDOW(widget));
if(w!=NULL)
    {self->r_focus_old=w;}
gtk_window_set_focus(GTK_WINDOW(widget),NULL);
return FALSE;
}
```

This sort of works, with exceptions:

- It catches double-clicks. Thus double-clicking in a GtkEntry selects its content, but moves focus to the main window.
- It does not react when clicking on a widget that already has a mouse handler that returns `TRUE` connected to it

To clarify, I want the basic behaviour of a webpage: If the user clicks outside an input field, it looses its focus to the container.

This is the callback that needs to be called when no other widget owns the keyboard:

```
void Application::keyDown(Anja::Window& win,int scancode,Anja::keymask_t keymask,int id)
{
if(m_engine && !m_keystate[scancode])
    {
    auto note=scancodeToMIDI(scancode);
    if(note!=0xff)
        {
        auto slot=scancodeToSlot(scancode);
        m_engine->messagePost(MIDI::Message
            {
             MIDI::StatusCodes::NOTE_ON
            ,static_cast<int>(m_session.waveformGet(slot).channel())
            ,note
            ,127
            });
        }
    else
        {
        auto ch=scancodeToChannel(scancode);
        if(ch>=0 && ch<16)
            {
            if(m_keystate[Keys::FADE_IN])
                {m_engine->fadeIn(ch,m_session.channel(ch).fadeTime());}
            else
            if(m_keystate[Keys::FADE_OUT])
                {m_engine->fadeOut(ch,m_session.channel(ch).fadeTime());}
            else
            if(m_keystate[Keys::FADE_IN_FAST])
                {m_engine->fadeIn(ch,1e-3f);}
            else
            if(m_keystate[Keys::FADE_OUT_FAST])
                {m_engine->fadeOut(ch,1e-3f);}
            }
        else
            {
            switch(scancode)
                {
                case Keys::AUDITION:
                    {
                    auto slot_current=m_session.slotActiveGet();
                    assert(slot_current>=0 && slot_current<128);
                    note=slotToMIDI(slot_current);
                    m_engine->messagePost(MIDI::Message{MIDI::StatusCodes::NOTE_ON,0,note|0x80,127});
                    }
                    break;

                case Keys::KILL_ALL:
                    for(size_t k=0;k<ChannelMixer::length();++k)
                        {m_engine->messagePost(MIDI::Message{MIDI::ControlCodes::SOUND_OFF,static_cast<int>(k),0});}
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
m_keystate[scancode]=1;
}
```

Comment: Sometimes there are easier ways to do things. What are you trying to do exactly? Do you have two windows? Are you trying to create a keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Here is what it is about: https://github.com/milasudril/anja. In particular, look at the keyboard callback in `ui/application.cpp`. When no input field is selected, keystrokes are pumped to JACK as MIDI messages. It is more like combining "Game"-style input with "Form"-style input. Also it should be easy to move focus out of any widget currently owning the keyboard.

Comment: Why would you not use a special text entry for the MIDI messages? Or then use the callback `key_release_event` and check if any text entry has the focus.

Comment: Sorry, I just reread the question. To move focus to a widget that is not a text entry, you will need to set `can focus` to True.

Comment: I know that. In the old version, the keyboard view did the job, but it is easier for the user if it is possible to release the keyboard by clicking outside anything. Also, the main window can already have focus so this comment does not apply. Maybe I need to override some callback for the GtkEntry. As said, the only major problem is that double-click is caught by the main window as well, which is stupid.